# Delay Tolerant Network(DTN) combining Information Centric Network via ONE simulator

Tags: java, one-simulator, dtn

How can I use the ONE simulator to implement the combination of the NDN network in a DTN network environment, can I add or extract the "content" of the packet or, at least a tag of a packet?

I have looked through many papers, but none of them used the ONE simulator for ICDTN simulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can "tag" and/or "add content" to messages using the [addProperty](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/blob/master/src/core/Message.java#L284) method (and read with getProperty). That's probably the best way forward here.